# Amortized Analysis On List

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

We want to have a set of `n` linear list to doing following operation:

`Insert(x,i)` : insert new elemets `x` on list `i`, and cost of this operation is `1`.

`Sum(i) :` calculate sum of all elements in list `i` and replace whole elements of list with the calculated `sum`, and cost is equal to number of elements in list `i` when we using this operation.

if we start with empty list and do the above operation in arbitrary manner, what is the amortized cost of each operation :

```
1)insert : 2, sum : 1
2)insert : 1, sum : 2
3)insert : 1, sum : n
4)insert : n, sum : 1
```

who can help me to understand how to solve this example and say why (2) is true?

Comment: Is there any more information on that sum-function. It seems rather strange to me that it can read $n$ elements, sum them up and store that one sum $n$ times in the list again for a cost $n$. ($n$ = number of elements in list)

Comment: Dear @MrTsjolder, NO, the sum of all elements is store 1 times instead of i's elements in list. i means i elements removed and the sum is insert as 1 element in list.

Comment: Would you know how that sum-function works more exactly then?

Comment: it read the list elemets 1...to i and add them and insert the sum as the first element. now, the total list elements is 1.

Comment: but that has a cost of $2n$ ($n$ for reading the elements, $n - 1$ times calculating a sum and $1$ for inserting the element again, not?

Comment: Dear @MrTsjolder, cost is n. (n for read and when read calculate sum, and inserting one elements i think is not important.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not quite familiar with amortized analysis, but I guess you could reason about it as follows (using the accounting method).

Say you charge an `insert` with $2\$$. Because you only need $1\$$ to perform the `insert`, you'll get for every inserted element in the list $1\$$ saving. This saving can be used when `sum` is being performed. For every element in the list, there is an extra $1\$$ left from the insertion and it can be used by `sum` to read the elements from the list, but then `sum`  has $1\$$ left to calculate the sum and store the element.

This way I would say (1) is the right answer, rather than (2), because in (2) there is no way to pay for your sum with only a constant factor if you don't have anything left from your insertions.

Comment: How (2) can be true?

Comment: That's the problem with your question. I can't believe 2 would be true (that's also why I needed this long for an answer)